# Instantiated a struct which is a part of iOS framework and has internal access control

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I would like to instantiate a struct which is a part of third party iOS framework and cannot be instantiated from outside means has internal init. But I need to create for Unit testing. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Writing Test Classes and Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH4-SW11) documentation states:

> Xcode provides a two-part solution to this problem:
>
> 1. When you set the `Enable Testability` build setting to `Yes`, which is true by default for test builds in new projects, Xcode includes the
>    `-enable-testing` flag during compilation. This makes the Swift entities declared in the compiled module eligible for a higher level of access.
> 2. When you add the `@testable` attribute to an import statement for a module compiled with testing enabled, you activate the elevated access
>    for that module in that scope. Classes and class members marked as
>    internal or public behave as if they were marked open. Other entities
>    marked as internal act as if they were declared public.

```
@testable import MySwiftFramework
```

Comment: @Wasim I am glad it worked. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)